# How to increase spark parallelism for task processing on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

am running a job on AWS EMR and I can see I have 945 core, and 5 cores per executor but only 1 task is being processed, how can I add more parallelism and increase performance to process more tasks ?

[image]

Comment: what kind of processing are you doing? something like, reading gzipped CSV or JSON file?